# Oracle SQL instantiate table of types dynamically in a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following types:

```
create or replace TYPE XXMC_CUST_OV_ACCT_TYP AS OBJECT (
  account_number        NUMBER
, account_description   VARCHAR2(1000)
, classification        VARCHAR2(200)
, account_type          VARCHAR2(50)
, sales_channel         VARCHAR2(100)
, date_established      DATE
, status                VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

AND

```
create or replace TYPE        "XXMC_TABLE_CUST" 
AS
  TABLE OF APPS.XXMC_CUST_OV_ACCT_TYP;
```

What I am trying to achieve is to `populate XXMC_TABLE_CUST` type with multiple types of `XXMC_CUST_OV_ACCT_TYP` using a single `SQL` query. I am able to do this via `PL/SQL` by looping through the cursor and extending the `XXMC_TABLE_CUST` with additional records, however I want to do it in a one liner `SQL` query.

If I try using this query to get multiple records of `XXMC_CUST_OV_ACCT_TYP` type:

```
SELECT XXMC_CUST_OV_ACCT_TYP
(10000||rownum, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '15-DEC-2003', 'Active') 
from HZ_PARTIES where rownum<4
```

then I get something like this in output:

```
[APPS.XXMC_CUST_OV_ACCT_TYP]

[APPS.XXMC_CUST_OV_ACCT_TYP]

[APPS.XXMC_CUST_OV_ACCT_TYP]
```

However, when I try to group these multiple records in a single `XXMC_TABLE_CUST` object using the query below:

```
SELECT XXMC_TABLE_CUST(
(SELECT XXMC_CUST_OV_ACCT_TYP
    (10000||rownum, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '15-DEC-2003', 'Active') from HZ_PARTIES where rownum<4
)) 
from DUAL;
```

I get the following error message:

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

How can I convert these multiple `XXMC_CUST_OV_ACCT_TYP` rows into a table of `XXMC_CUST_OV_ACCT_TYP`?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't `select cast(multiset(select * from hz_party) as xxmc_table_cust) from dual` what You are looking for?

Comment: @PonderStibbons this is exactly what I need, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Ponder Stibbons in the comment above:

```
select cast(multiset(select * from hz_party) as xxmc_table_cust) from dual
```